# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'grd'

Tags: python

I know this has been asked many times before on this site, but none of the solutions have helped me. I am running the following script which gives me the error in the title:

```
import numpy as np
import fatiando as ft

shape = (41, 41)
x, y = ft.grd.regular((-10, 10, 30, 50), shape)
height = 800 - 1000*ft.utils.gaussian2d(x, y, 3, 1, x0=0, y0=37)
rel = -7000*ft.utils.gaussian2d(x, y, 3, 5, x0=0, y0=40)
thick = height - rel
dens = 1900*np.ones_like(thick)
data = np.transpose([x, y, height, thick, dens])
with open('layers.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write("# Synthetic layer model of sediments and topography\n")
    f.write("# Columns are:\n")
    f.write("#   lon   lat   height   thickness   density\n")
    np.savetxt(f, data, fmt='%g')
ft.vis.figure(figsize=(4, 3))
ft.vis.title('Depth of sediments [m]')
ft.vis.axis('scaled')
ft.vis.pcolor(x, y, rel, shape)
ft.vis.colorbar()
ft.vis.savefig('depth.png')
ft.vis.figure(figsize=(4, 3))
ft.vis.title('Topography [m]')
ft.vis.axis('scaled')
ft.vis.pcolor(x, y, height, shape)
ft.vis.colorbar()
ft.vis.savefig('topography.png')
ft.vis.figure(figsize=(4, 3))
ft.vis.title('Thickness of sediment layer [m]')
ft.vis.axis('scaled')
ft.vis.pcolor(x, y, thick, shape)
ft.vis.colorbar()
ft.vis.savefig('thickness.png')
ft.vis.show()
```

This script is not my own creation, but a pre-packaged demo script with a program I have installed (Tesseroids), so I don't know why I am getting errors when using it. I have installed fatiando.

Comment: Perhaps the version of fatiando is newer or older than the program above and the modules have since been renamed. Check if the program specifies a version of fatiando that it requires.

Comment: The user guide doesn't specify any specific version, that I could find at least. Another commentor suggested the .grd command has been renamed .gridder, but that gave me the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that fatiando.grd has been renamed to fatiando.gridder . Imports OK for me if I do it this way:

```
import numpy as np
import fatiando as ft
from fatiando import gridder

shape = (41, 41)
x, y = gridder.regular((-10, 10, 30, 50), shape)
```

I found the change in the project's [github repository](https://github.com/leouieda/fatiando/commit/d0e508ecc9d5cee82f8346f2186833496fd48868).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I got the same error with 'gridder' unfortunately.

Comment: Sorry, so did I, when I tested it. Edited my answer -- please try again.

Comment: Thank you, that has fixed the gridder error, but now I am getting errors with other ft. commands. I will have a look through the github repository and see if I can solve them myself. Cheers.